# Generating a series of prime numbers using recursion in ruby

Tags: ruby, recursion, sequence

I am trying to generate a list of prime nos b/w 1-100 in ruby. I have initally done this through an iterative method which works well.

```
require 'prime'

def Primenos(n)
 Prime.prime?(n)
end

def f1
  (1..100).collect do |e|
    if Primenos(e)
      then p "this is prime - #{e}"
    end
  end
end

f1
```

But I would also like to know if this could be done recursively ? Any idea?

Comment: Sure, this can be written recursively, as can most methods that employ iteration, but it is a trivial sort of recursion that is less efficient and more opaque than simple iteration. Note that method and variable names customarily begin with a lower-case letter, and must do so when there are no arguments. Consider writing you rmethod as follows: `enum = Prime.each; loop do; n = enum.next; break if n > 100; p "this is prime - #{n}"; end`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `Prime.each(100){|pr| p "this is prime - #{pr}" }`

Comment: @steenslag, thanks. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Other option:

```
require 'prime'
def primes_smaller_than(num, res=[])
  return res if num < 2
  res << num if Prime.prime?(num)
  primes_smaller_than(num - 1, res)
end

primes_smaller_than 100
#=> [97, 89, 83, 79, 73, 71, 67, 61, 59, 53, 47, 43, 41, 37, 31, 29, 23, 19, 17, 13, 11, 7, 5, 3, 2]
```

To print it out:

```
primes_smaller_than(100).each { |e| puts "this is prime - #{e}" }
```